# Limit column value repeats to top 2

Tags: sql, ansi-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    Search.USER_ID,
    Search.SEARCH_TERM,
    COUNT(*) AS Search.count
FROM Search

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Which returns a response that looks like this:

```
USER_ID   SEARCH_TERM    count
bob       dog            50
bob       cat            45
sally     cat            38
john      mouse          30
sally     turtle         10
sally     lion           5
john      zebra          3
john      leopard        1
```

And my question is: How would I change the query, so that it only returns the top 2 most-searched-for-terms for any given user? So in the example above, the last row for Sally would be dropped, and the last row for John would also be dropped, leaving a total of 6 rows; 2 for each user, like so:

```
USER_ID   SEARCH_TERM    count
bob       dog            50
bob       cat            45
sally     cat            38
john      mouse          30
sally     turtle         10
john      zebra          3
```

Comment: Which database engine? There are some that have easier ways to do this and some that need more work

Comment: Sorry, should have provided that info to begin with - It's running in Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can put the original query into a CTE, add the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Then in the new main query, just add a `WHERE` clause to limit by the row number. Your query would look something like this:

```
;WITH OriginalQuery AS
(
    SELECT 
        s.[User_id]
        ,s.Search_Term
        ,COUNT(*) AS 'count'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.[USER_ID] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM Search s
    GROUP BY s.[User_id], s.Search_Term
)
SELECT oq.User_id
      ,oq.Search_Term
      ,oq.count
FROM OriginalQuery oq
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY oq.count DESC
```

EDIT: I specified SQL Server as the dbms I used here, but the above should be ANSI-compliant and work in Snowflake.

Comment: I̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶m̶e̶n̶t̶i̶o̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶S̶n̶o̶w̶f̶l̶a̶k̶e̶.̶ ̶W̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶v̶e̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶:̶ ̶`̶S̶Q̶L̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶i̶l̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶:̶ ̶s̶y̶n̶t̶a̶x̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶1̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶1̶ ̶u̶n̶e̶x̶p̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶'̶W̶I̶T̶H̶'̶.̶`̶
I'm bad at sql and after some minor tweaking, I managed to get this to run in snowflake, and it worked exactly as I needed it to. Thanks!